# how to you make an image change it's alpha when touched

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, alpha, uicontrol

**The button is not a `UIButton`, it's a subclass of `UIControl`**

When the user taps my `UIControl`, I want to change the alpha so the user has some visual feedback that it's being pressed. Then change it again when released

```
UIImageView *mask =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 58, 58)];
mask.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"centerButton.png"];
mask.center = self.center;
mask.center = CGPointMake(mask.center.x, mask.center.y+3);
[self addSubview:mask];
```

The center button was created using [a tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) on [rayWenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) for learning about creating custom controls.

**I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to reference the center image.**

Here is my .h class

```
@interface OOTRotaryWheel : UIControl


@property (weak) id <OOTRotaryProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *container;
@property int numberOfSections;
@property CGAffineTransform startTransform;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *sectors;
@property int currentSector;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *mask;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)del withSections:(int)sectionsNumber;
- (void)rotate;
- (void) buildSectorsEven;
- (void) buildSectorsOdd;

@end
```

So how do I detect a touch down on the UIImageView and touch up? and make it more like a button (so when i can load another xib or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To change the alpha use: `mask.alpha = 0.0f;`**

**To do this with `IBActions`:**
To act when the button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressedDown{
      mask.alpha = 0.5f;
}//Connect this IBAction to touchDown
```

To change the button back to it's original Alpha:

```
-(IBAction)buttonUpInsideAndOutside{
      mask.alpha = 1.0f;
}//Connect this IBAction to touchUpInside and touchUpOutside
```

---

**To do this with `UITouches`:**
To act when the button is pressed:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      UITouch*touch = [touches anyObject];
      if(touch.view==mask)
            mask.alpha = 0.5f;
}//Will only work if the IBOutlet is connected
```

To change the button back to it's original Alpha:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      mask.alpha = 1.0f;
}//Will only work if the IBOutlet is connected
```

**This will work, wether you have a xib/storyboard interface or not.**

Comment: I think you mean "touchUpInside" instead of "buttonUpInside".

Comment: Yes but the Xib is empty. The controls are created in code. (Please see the site because I followed the tutorial). I made Mask a variable in the property

Comment: If the mask variable isn't global, make it global, because that would be the most efficient way. Otherwise, you would use this cool advanced for loop, but it's not as efficient, try the UITouches method, it should work, and if it doesn't I will show you your 2 other options.